# componentDidMount and componentWillMount() not working on datatable using ajax React

Tags: reactjs, datatable, babeljs

I want to load my dataTable on react using AJAX before mounting the response data. 
 Data is updating but the table does load properly on view

At the bottom of the table displaying **NO DATA AVAILABLE ON THE TABLE**  and when clearing the search bar of the dataTable after search the data does not load anymore.

Is there a way to use AJAX response data on React before Mounting Component 
I already use **componentWillMount** and **componentDidMount** but the table does not worki properly

I'm using the below code to display.

```
 component[Will/Did]Mount() {

   $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      success:function(data){

        var obj = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          obj[i] = {
            'id': data[i].id,
            'name': data[i].title,
            'desc': data[i].body     
          };
        }
        this.setState({TRs: obj})

     }.bind(this)
   })

 }
```

You can visit the project here @codepen [Crud React Table](http://codepen.io/private_ryan/pen/RVBdpO?editors=0011)
Hope you can help me for this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use a "work around" way here, based on react's component life cycle.

So, the idea is to use `state` (let's say its name is `renderTextOnly`), which will be initially set in constructor, then will be changed in the ajax callback:

- First, when the state is not yet updated, you display "NO DATA AVAILABLE ON THE TABLE" on your table
- Then, in the ajax callback (after new data come,) just re-set that state, and display your data on the table

The real code may look something like:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        renderTextOnly: true,       
    };

}

 component[Will/Did]Mount() {

   $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      success:function(data){

        var obj = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          obj[i] = {
            'id': data[i].id,
            'name': data[i].title,
            'desc': data[i].body     
          };
        }
        this.setState({TRs: obj, renderTextOnly: false});

     }.bind(this)
   })

 }

_renderTextOnly() { 
    // here just returns a simple div with your text
    return (
        <div style={{}}>
            NO DATA AVAILABLE ON THE TABLE
        </div>          
    );
}   

render() {
    if (this.state.renderTextOnly) {
        return this._renderTextOnly();
    }       
    //display your table here, this will not change your logic, just need to add the above 3 lines for this render method
    return (
        <div>RENDER YOUR TABLE HERE</div>       
    );
}
```

The above way was used in my actual project, feel free to try and post here some errors if any, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reply but another thing is that after using the search box the dataTable  does not display any data after clearing the text field. it looks like the state is updated but the data from datatable does not really rendered

Comment: It may relate to how you render the search box and the table. could you please post more code here?

Comment: hey sir looks like i figure out how to update data Thanks for the help about the renderTextOnly state. I change the ** return this._renderTextOnly function to  this.componentDidMount  ** to load the mounting again and it works THANKS A LOT here@codepen http://codepen.io/private_ryan/pen/RVBdpO?editors=0011

Comment: If this works, please consider an up-vote for my idea, thanks. However, I am not so sure the way you call this.componentDidMount(). If you can post more code, we can figure out the more proper way, I think